# How to add facebook post like to website

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

I want to add facebook post like when user clicks on it.

Example:

this is my facebook post link.

> https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=115308402188346&id=100011275598659

```
<div class="my-post"><a href="link">Like My Post</div>
```

I want this to open in dialog box and want to record callback weather user like it or not.

how can i do that?

Comment: any clues in the [facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript) that's linked in the [tag:facebook-javascript-sdk] tag you used for this question?

Comment: There is option of opening a dialogbox using that but i am unable to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.5

Use the `edge.create` event to listen for likes. This only works for external websites with the [Like Button plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button), of course you can´t listen for likes on facebook.com and the plugin only works for external links or Facebook Pages (NOT posts on those).

"Posting a Like" is not possible with just a link, especially if there is no user authorization. The only "like" that is possible with the API is `og.likes`, it´s explained in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/og.likes

That´s only possible for your own Open Graph Objects though. What you want to achieve is not possible at all (in a legal way).

Comment: But i dont want to add like button. It allows me to add only facebook pages.

I want to add like for every post as well

http://puu.sh/mVppT/d53a16b898.png

Like this

Comment: but i saw that people are doing that that's why i am searching for that thing

Comment: please read the last part of my answer, i added information about posting likes. i missed that part of your question, the first part of my answer is about listening for likes.

Comment: Thanks luschn I also found that thing before only but visit this site.

http://kingdomlikes.com/free_points/facebook-post-likes

It is making that thing happen.

And working great.

If you can make account on that and do research than will be great.

Uptill now i am able to get popup via embedded post api of from facebook.

Comment: that´s what i expected. those platforms should not get used, they should get reported. like exchange platforms are illegal. you should read the platform policy: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Comment: 13.3: "Don’t participate in any “like” or “share” exchange programs."

Comment: I am not participating in any program but i wanted to show you that example and wanted to show you that there must be any method to achieve that

Comment: i just quoted the policy. that kingdomlikes page is a clear violation of the facebook policy. there is no legal way. legal being the important keyword ;)

Comment: may i ask why you want to do that anyway? users can just open the link and like the entry directly on facebook.

Comment: I wanted to allow user download the freebies by gifting like to my post.

Comment: that´s not allowed either. you really need to read the platform policy, you are not allowed to reward users in any way for liking or sharing.